# Linux: Compressing all .pdf files recursively (.tar)

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

At the linux command line, I'd like to compress all .pdf files in a directory, any of it's subdirectories and so on - but only .pdf files. I'm struggling to figure out the syntax, any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `find -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cf docs.tar`

Answer (score 2):

PDF files are binary files and probably won't *compress* much. `tar` doesn't compress anyway, without the `-z` option, and it would leave the uncompressed PDF files in place.

But if you want to try compressing PDF files, you could use

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec gzip {} \;
```

This will compress all PDF files (and only PDF files) in folders below the current directory.

Each `filename.pdf` will be replaced by `filename.pdf.gz`

Comment: How do you uncompress all the files later?