# linux zip and tar all files with a specific extenstion recursively maintaining directory structure

Tags: linux, centos, find, tar

Similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/299938) and this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/299448) I'd like to make a single compressed tar file (files.tar.gz) that contains all the php files in my webroot and all it's subdirectories, maintaining folder structure. My webroot is called 'public_html'.

I have not tried anything yet because I'm not sure where to start.
The second question that I linked actually comes pretty close to what I'm looking for, but it makes each found file a separate GZ, if I read it right.

Actually, the monolithic nature of the tar is more important to me than the compression of gzip. I just want to pull this file onto my windows machine where I can search through it with the tools I am used to.

Comment: I think I need to check my facts. I just tested `find .  -name '*.html' -print | xargs echo` in my own webroot. it prints a **single line**. Thus example 2 you linked to creates a single file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rf php_backup.tar`

This uses the second answer you linked to, but replaces the `-c` with `-r`

From man tar:

> ```
> -c      Create a new archive containing the specified items.
> -r      Like -c, but new entries are appended to the archive.  Note that
>         this only works on uncompressed archives stored in regular files.
>         The -f option is required.
> ```

An other option would be to replace the -print0 with -exec. I think that will be more efficient, but it might break if you have thousands or ten of thousands of files.

**[Edit]**

1) The -print0 and -0 after xargs are only needed if you have inconvenient separators in your filenames. (read names with spaces). You might not need those.

2) I checked the command again and tested it. `find /public_www  -name '*.php' -print | xargs`  feeds a single line to xargs. Thus the example you linked to translates to something like `xargs -0 tar -cf docs.tar *.php` and should also work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first version and as far as i can tell it worked perfectly, but it's good to have the additional info for the next user.